# add date in bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a text file that I receive from a partner.  The file gets imported into our SQL using a temp table in a SQL Job.  The process is we create a temp table, then bulk insert the text file into the temp file and then into the SQL table.  Here is what it looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE #apt_mkdn(
    [PJ_RES_ID_PRG] [int] NULL,
    [PJ_REBATE_ID] [int] NULL,
    [PJ_REBATE_DATE] [datetime] NULL
)

bulk insert #apt_mkdn from '\markdown.txt' 
with (FIELDTERMINATOR='|',ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a', FIRSTROW=2)

go

insert into PROJECT_INFO(PJ_RES_ID_PRG,PJ_REBATE_ID,PJ_REBATE_DATE)
SELECT
PJ_RES_ID_PRG,PJ_REBATE_ID,PJ_REBATE_DATE  FROM #apt_mkdn
go

drop table #apt_mkdn
go
```

In the table PROJECT_INFO there is a field for import date.  What I need to do is to add this date using getdate() or similar function to the table for all of the records that have just been inserted.  I hope this makes sense.

I have tried to add importdate to both the insert statement and the select statement like

```
    insert into PROJECT_INFO(PJ_RES_ID_PRG,PJ_REBATE_ID,PJ_REBATE_DATE, ImportDate)
    SELECT
    PJ_RES_ID_PRG,PJ_REBATE_ID,PJ_REBATE_DATE, getdate()  
    FROM #apt_mkdn
    go
```

I get errors each time.

Comment: Sharing the error message would go miles to helping people understand the problem.

Comment: Here is the error on the date:

Comment: Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 39 (ImportDate). [SQLSTATE 42000]

Comment: That is a pretty clear indication you are trying to insert into a date/datetime column and the source data has an invalid value.

Comment: I have the field defined in the table as datetime, I am using the getdate() function.  Do I need to format the date somehow?  All I want to do is to update each row with the current date as I am inserting the records.